# jpa many to many child list not persisted

Tags: jpa, many-to-many

I have a senario where there is an entity Article, an entity Author and a join table Article_Author. Article and Author have a many to many relationship ( on article can have many authors and an author can have many articles).
here are my entities classes :
Author class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="AUTHOR")
@NamedQuery(name="Author.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM Author a")
public class Author implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="AUTHOR_CODE")
    private String authorCode;

    private String nom;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to Article
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
        name="ARTICLE_AUTHOR"
        , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="AUTHOR")
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="ART_REF")
            }
        )
    private List<Article> article;
 }
 //getters and setters + hashcode and equals methods
```

Article class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ARTICLE_TEST")
@NamedQuery(name="ArticleTest.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM ArticleTest a")
public class ArticleTest implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="ART_REF")
    private String artRef;

    @Column(name="ART_TITRE")
    private String artTitre;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to AutheurTest
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="articleTests", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<AutheurTest> autheurTests;
  //getters and setters + hashcode and equals methods
}
```

and here is the code where I create an article and attach one author (for testing) :

```
            //.....
            AutheurTest aut1 = new AutheurTest();
            AutheurTest aut2 = new AutheurTest();

            aut1.setAutheurCode("1");
            aut1.setNom("AUT1");
            articlemodelBean.createautheurtest(aut1);
            ArticleTest art1 = new ArticleTest();           
            art1.setArtRef("A");
            art1.setArtTitre("ART1");       
            articlemodelBean.dmlArticle_test(art1,"insert"); //persist art1
            AutheurTest newaut = articlemodelBean.getAuteurActive_test(aut1.getAutheurCode());      

                ArticleTest  foundedart =  articlemodelBean.findArticle_test(art1.getArtRef()); //getting the article 

                foundedart.getAutheurTests().add(newaut);

                articlemodelBean.artaut(foundedart); //merge foudedart
        //.....
```

So I'm not getting any error, both the article and author are added to database! but the foreign keys are not inserted into the join table. so basically the author is not attached to the article.

Comment: Please post real code that would compile. And post all the relevant code. We have no idea what AutheurTest is, what your horribly named methods do, etc. But anyway, if you don't add the article to the author's list of articles, JPA won't persist the association.

Comment: I posted the code that I thought relevant sorry! I will edit and add the detailed methods..
I will give it a try but could you please explain Wwhy it would work by adding the article to the author's list of articles and not in the other way ( adding the author to the article's list of authors) like I did ?

Comment: Because the owning side of the association is Author.article. The other side, which has the mappedBy attribute, is the inverse side. And JPA only cares about the owning side.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I created and persisted the authors, than created the article, attributed the article to each author and then merge author, persist article. and it worked !